# Object Localization Keras | Predicts the whole image

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to predict an object position within an image using a simple Convolutional Neural Network but the given prediction is always the full image.

- The dataset is Stanford Cars Dataset which contains about 8144 car images.
- I am not trying to predict which type of car it is, only it's position
- The features are 200x200 grayscale images, rescaled between [0,1]
- The labels are LeftX,TopY,Width,Height. Also rescaled between [0,1]

Here is the model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape = (200,200,1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="Adam",metrics=[])
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=32, validation_split=0,epochs=30,verbose=2)
```

The model's predictions basically always are: [0,0,1,1].

Comment: Why do you feed the images rescaled to area of 1? Why do you rescale it?

Comment: You actually don't need the last layer model.add(Activation("sigmoid")) because this is a regression model

Comment: @LucaMassaron No, sigmoid can also be used for regression, when the targets are in the [0, 1] range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, i have used pretrained xception network to function as the feature extractor. You can experiment with other Imagenet models like inception, resnet50 etc. tf.keras.applications provides a good number of pretrained convnets. Using a pretrained network can help you to get good results even with little data. [more about transfer learning](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/)

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception  

inp = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
base_model = Xception(include_top=False, input_tensor=inp, weights='imagenet')
y = base_model.layers[-1].output
y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)
y = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(y)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=y)
```

the output shape is [None, 4], meaning that each label consists of 4 numbers

- x - x coordinate of the center of the bounding box
- y - y coordinate of the center of the bounding box
- w - width of the bounding box
- h - height of the bounding box

The labels are re-scaled to lie between 0 and 1. (re-scaled with respect to the image dimensions)

sample bounding box label for the image
[image: cat]

```
[0.48, 0.4 , 0.58, 0.37]
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer! I cannot test it tonight but will surely give it a try tomorrow.

So basically if I understand well, I should Preload the model just as you did and train model with my  features (image pixels) and on my labels (coordinates,width and height), is that right?

Comment: yes thats right, but if you are using my code you have to make sure that your labels are in the correct format and scaled to lie between  [0,1]

Comment: It works! Altough it's not super precise, (probably a lack of training), the model seems to predict good bounding boxes, thank you!!

So again, if my understanding is good, it worked because the model (Xception) was already trained so It did not have to start from random weights ?

But should it technically work with the model that I had before where I only gave it positions without even teaching it what a car was?

thanks.

Comment: Yes it should work with random initialization, provided you have enough examples in your dataset. If you have less examples and if your dataset has images/examples similar to those present in the dataset of pre trained model only then you might be better off with transfer learning.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following architecture in case if you want to implement it using PyTorch

```
class ResNetModel(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(ResNetModel, self).__init__()
    resnet = models.resnet34(pretrained=True)
    layers = list(resnet.children())[:8]
    self.features1 = torch.nn.Sequential(*layers[:6])
    self.features2 = torch.nn.Sequential(*layers[6:])
    self.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(512), torch.nn.Linear(512, 7))
    self.bb = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(512), torch.nn.Linear(512, 4))
    
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.features1(x)
    x = self.features2(x)
    x = torch.nn.functional.relu(x)
    x = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))(x)
    x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
    y_class = torch.nn.functional.softmax(self.classifier(x), dim=1)
    return y_class, self.bb(x)
```

You can find the whole notebook on the link below.

https://www.kaggle.com/shweta2407/objectdetection-on-custom-dataset-resnet34